Lanthanum trifluoride dimer vs dilanthanum hexafluoride
I was seeing the name of $\ce{La2F6}$ and it's called lanthanum trifluoride dimer. Then I also found $\ce{Fe2F6}$ which is named diiron hexafluoride. Why $\ce{La2F6}$ is named like that, and not dilanthanum hexafluoride, when the chemical formula is essentially the same?
Is it something related to the structural formula?

"I was seeing the name of F6La2 and it's called Lanthanum Trifluoride Dimer." Where have you seen this? Link please.

A molecule dimer is when two molecules joined by intermolecular forces (e.g Carboxylic acid Dimer). When two molecules are joined by a bond like B2H6, it isn't a dimer (Borane).

@ChemLover68 That's not true.
